# Getting class name and method name in Ruby

Tags: ruby

Say I have,

```
class Foo
  def self.bar
    puts "I want to print #{some_method_for_class_name} and #{some_method_for_method_name}."
  end
end
```

Is there some way to get "Foo" and "bar" in the place for `some_method_for_class_name` and `some_method_for_method_name` respectively?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
class Foo
  def self.bar
    puts "I want to print #{self} and #{__method__}."
  end
end
```

If it was not a class method you'd need to use `self.class` instead.